# Try to install Shopify Slate(Windows) but it doen`t work

Tags: node.js, npm, shopify, yarnpkg, slate

Try to install Shopify Slate on Windows but it doesn`t work. I need your help, guys!

npm version:

> 6.9.0

yarn version:

> 1.17.3

gulp version:

> CLI version: 2.2.0
>   Local version: 4.0.2

I do install like this:

> npm install -g @shopify/slate

Result:

> npm WARN deprecated natives@1.1.6: This module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x.
>   C:\Users\Marshall\AppData\Roaming\npm\slate -> C:\Users\Marshall\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@shopify\slate\lib\index.js
>   + @shopify/slate@0.14.0
>   removed 658 packages and updated 1 package in 67.394s

Is it OK or not?

I would like to get full step-by-step instruction how to install Shopify Slate(on Windows) and fix my problem! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Slate doesn't yet officially support Windows.

System requirements: https://shopify.github.io/slate/docs/system-requirements#windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl

The documentation above states that it only supports MacOS at this time however there is a workaround that could potentially get it working in Windows. To do that, you'll need to use WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

Further reading: https://github.com/Shopify/slate/issues/667